# How to identify what file descriptors are associated to STDIN, STDOUT etc

Tags: stdout, file-descriptors, stdin

I seem to remember some command or envvar that tells you this.
I'd like basically something that executed on terminal, for instance, give you

```
echo $STDIN 
/dev/tty
echo $STDOUT
/dev/tty
fdescribe 0 or fdescribe /dev/stdin
/dev/tty
fdescribe 1 or fdescribe /dev/stdout
/dev/tty
```

but that can be executed in a script or subprocess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, fd 0 is associated to stdin and fd 1 to stdout by definition.

If you want to know what *files* are opened on those fds in a (Bourne-like or csh-like¹) shell, you can do:

```
lsof -ap "$$" -d 0-1
```

On Linux or Cygwin, see also:

```
realpath /dev/stdin /dev/stdout
```

Though the output is less useful if it's sockets or pipes.

On Linux again, adding `-E` to `lsof` gives more information for some types of files such as pipes, pseudo-ttys or some sockets as to what's at the other end if any.

Recent versions of `util-linux` also have a `lsfd` utility (Linux-specific) that can give you some of the same information as `lsof`:

```
lsfd -p "$$" -Q '(fd == 0) or (fd == 1)'
```

Or

```
lsfd -p "$$" -Q 'assoc =~ "^[01]$"'
```

---

<sup>¹ in rc-like shells use `$pid` instead of `$$` and in `fish`: `$fish_pid`</sup>

Comment: Looks like I mixed up my memories. I was looking indeed for $TTY envar. But it is not what I need now, what i needed to attack my problem is your brilliant answer. Thanks again!!!!